# Internal Server Error when trying password auth and rewrite engine

Tags: apache, .htaccess, .htpasswd

we want to utilize Rewrite Engine utility and password protection in the same directory, we created `.htaccess` file for it, but unfortunatly it is not working and giving `Internal Server Error` what might the cause of it, or what we are doing wrong ?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ admin.php/$1 [L]

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Nokia"
AuthUserFile .htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

`.htpasswd` file is in same directory

Comment: Can you post your full htaccess?

Comment: @starkeen this is full htaccess file

Comment: What happens if you remove the authorisation code, do you still get an Internal server error?

Comment: @starkeen no i don't get any error after removing authorization code